# C# and SQL Server error with "CREATE DATABASE" statement

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

Here is my code:

```
String str;
SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;Integratedsecurity=SSPI;database=master");             

str = "CREATE DATABASE JoesData ON PRIMARY " +
      "(NAME = JoesData, " +
      "FILENAME = 'C:\\JoesData.mdf', " +
      "SIZE = 3MB, MAXSIZE = 10MB, FILEGROWTH = 10%) " +
      "LOG ON (NAME = MyDatabase_Log, " +
      "FILENAME = 'C:\\MyJLog.ldf', " +
      "SIZE = 1MB, " +
      "MAXSIZE = 5MB, " +
      "FILEGROWTH = 10%)";

SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(str, myConn);
try
{
   myConn.Open();
   myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
   MessageBox.Show("DataBase is Created Successfully", "MyProgram", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "MyProgram", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
finally
{
   if (myConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
   {
      myConn.Close();
   }
}
```

Here is the error:
[image]

Any idea what might be causing this? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Please paste the text of the error into your question.

Comment: You can write error code here instead of flickr photo :-)

Comment: The error says that the SQL Server instance was not found or was not accessible. That should be pretty self explanatory for the origin of the problem => your SQL Server instance was not found or was not accessible.

Comment: Does the script work if you run it in MS SSMS?  Do you have a named instance? .\SQLExpress for example.

Comment: Also, please update your title to be more specific about the error you are getting.

Comment: This gives a complete rundown...http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2007/03/31/named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Your database connection is failing.  Check your installation and your connection string.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you can't connect to the default SQL Server instance running on the host machine.

This can be for a variety of reasons.

Its not installed and started, maybe you don't have the right priviliges? Is there a problem with the Integrated Security, are you in the right server role?

It could even be more obscure, say you have `localhost` mapped to a remote IP address in you hosts file but, that is less likely.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be as silly as this typo in your connection string??

Instead of:

```
Server=localhost;Integratedsecurity=SSPI;database=master
```

try:

```
Server=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;database=master
```

note the *SPACE* between the `Integrated` and `Security`

Answer (score 0):

Try providing the Username and password in the connection string